# Contador de palabras con acentos

Tags: python-3.x

¿Alguien conoce alguna manera de contar las palabras que llevan acento?

- Ejemplo: canción, ecuación, hola
- Resultado: canción, ecuación

Comment: Todas las palabras tienen acento, pero sólo algunas necesitan signos de acentuación (acento gráfico o tilde). ¿Te refieres a cualquier acento gráfico (diéresis, eñe, etc) o sólo a las tildes que van sobre las vocales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta expresíon sirve para encontrarlos:

```
con_acento = []
palabras = ['guión', 'gato', 'fusíl', 'casa', 'Ábracadabra']
for p in palabras:
    if re.search(r'[À-ÿ]', p):
        con_acento.append(p)
```

Si quieres contar, solo necesitas determinar cuantos elementos hay en la lista:

```
len(con_acento)
```

Pero como explicó el usuario @abulafia en los comentarios, esto va a capturar todos los caracteres non-ascii Unicode como `ñ, Ñ, ç, Ç, Æ, æ, Ø, ø, etc` ademas de `á, é, í ...` ... si es importante que sólo captures caracteres específicos, puedes usar una clase de caracteres menos ancha en la regex, como esta: `re.search(r'[ÁÉÍÓÚÑáéíóúñ]', p)`

Comment: Quizás el rango de letras unicode que has puesto en la expresión regular es excesivo. Con ese rango te contaría como "palabra con acento" también las que no tengan acentos, pero sí ñ, Ñ, ç, Ç, y otras muchas letras menos comunes como Æ, æ, Ø, ø, etc. Vale, podemos suponer que estas "raras" no aparecerían, pero ¿por qué no ser más explícitos en la expresión regular y poner sólo acentos: `[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]`?

Comment: Es posible es mi mal español :), pero yo  pensaba que él quiere capturar todos caractares con cualquier tipo de acento, incluyendo [ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú], pero tambien otros como ñ, ü etc ... pero sí, si solo quieres el acento como á, é, etc, el clase de caracteres es mejor

Comment: Y si es importante que la programa no captura letras como Ø, Æ, etc, el clase de caracteres es necesario. Voy a mencionarla en mi contesta, gracias.

Comment: Estrictamente hablando, en castellano las letras con acentos son las que he mencionado en la clase de caracteres. El castellano no tiene acentos graves (è,à) ni circunflejos (ô). Y los dos puntos se denominan diéresis y sólo pueden aparecer sobre la ü. La ñ es una letra en sí misma y nunca es considerada como una "n con acento". En todo caso, muchas veces he visto a gente decir "detectar acentos" queriendo decir en realidad "detectar caracteres no-ascii". Si la pregunta se refería a ésto, tu respuesta sería la adecuada.

Comment: @abulafia estrictamente hablando, solo las palabras tienen acento, lo correcto es hablar de las tildes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Si tan sólo necesitas contar las vocales con tilde pues este código te servirá. Resalto que dijiste **contar** en tu pregunta.

```
vocales_con_tilde = ['á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú']
palabras = ['hola', 'canción', 'allá', 'python', 'esdrújula']
contador_con_acento = 0

for vocal in vocales_con_tilde:
    if any(vocal in s for s in palabras):
        contador_con_acento += 1
```